# Получение файлов с сервера на веб клиент JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, файлы, клиент-сервер

Есть сайт на JavaSсript, есть сервер на котором развернута база и PHP скрипты. Встал вопрос необходимости скачивания файлов пользователем. Проблем с файлами из каталога сервера нет, вопрос можно ли как то получить то, что лежит за ним?
Я знаю что JS вроде такое не дает делать, но может можно как то через PHP передавать? У PHP на сервере доступ ко всем файлам же есть.
В общем любые советы привествуются, потому как в интернете ничего годного я по этому вопросу не нашел.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

U.P.D. Если вдруг кто-то столкнется с такой проблемой, нашел обходной путь через PHP. Так как у него есть доступ на сервере ко всем папкам, а не только к корневой как у JS, можно копировать файлы в папку транзит в корне сайта скриптом PHP и скачивать с помощью Js уже оттуда. Большие файлы,ествественно, таким образом лучше не обрабатывать + папку надо очищать.

Answer (score 0):

А в чем проблема ? Получаете полный путь к файлу с сервера и вставляете в тег "a" и добавляете аттрибут download

Вот пример: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12094080/download-files-from-server-php

Comment: проблема в том,что в этих примерах файлы берут из корневой папки, а мне нужно вытащить файл за ее пределами, или я чего-то не понял в примерах..

Comment: куда за пределы? переместить файл имеете ввиду?

Comment: сервер запущен на OpenServer, внутри его директории есть папка localhost с самим js, внутри этой папки доступ ко всем файлам у меня есть, но мне надо получить файл, допустим, из корневой папки диска

Comment: имеете ввиду допустим получить файл с диска C: ?

Comment: да, файлы которые мне нужны лежать в корне диска

Comment: нельзя так. Защита есть)